# How do you delete an item from a json array after PHP decoding it if it satisfies a certain condition?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am pretty new to php in general so I apologize if this might seem like a dumb question or if I don't make sense.

Here is my code to merge multiple JSON files:

```
<?php
$files = glob("*.json");
$newDataArray = [];
foreach($files as $file){
    $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
    $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
    $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
}
$newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
file_put_contents("merged.json",$newDataJSON);
?>
```

Now that I finally got this working, I have one more task at hand that is driving me mad. I am trying to take the `$newDataJSON` and loop through all `data.user.products` items. I need to completely remove items  that have 0 stock before saving the final json.

JSON Structure example:

```
[0]
->user
-->products
--->[0]
---->title Red Bike
---->stock 0
--->[2]
---->title Yellow Bike
---->stock 58
--->[3]
---->title Green Bike
---->stock 0
[1]
->user
-->products
--->[0]
---->title Red Skateboard
---->stock 23
--->[2]
---->title Yellow Skateboard
---->stock 0
--->[3]
---->title Green Skateboard
---->stock 20
```

So in this example I would remove [0]'s [0] and [3] because the stock is zero and I would remove [1]'s [2] because the stock is zero.

Route I have been trying variations of that failed is:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('merged.json');
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['stock'] == 0) {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
    unset($json_arr[$i]);
}
$json_arr = array_values($json_arr);
file_put_contents('cleaned.json', json_encode($json_arr));
?>
```

I am not sure if I am even on the right track here, I guess I don't know how to navigate the array correctly.

Any idea how I would go about this if even possible? I have tried a few things without success. I can't seem to figure it out completely. Any help is so much appreciated. Thank you

Sample JSON:

```
[{"status":true,"user":{"username":"Chris","avatar":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/avatars\/iiPjqYlVkijUv9XoPt0YUpyHuueBdkFkrTjIwnJd.gif","rep":{"positive":1,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"JucpDM8","title":"Non-Full Access(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png","path":"product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png"},"quantity":{"min":25,"max":1000000},"price":0.02,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":500,"type":"account","stock":12},{"id":"qX4vLC2","title":"Unmigrated(UFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg","path":"product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":5.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"sYu98Kq","title":"Semi-Full(SFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg","path":"product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"7efhwnl","title":"Optifine Cape","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg","path":"product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":2,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"kBkgLAv","title":"Hypixel Ranked(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png","path":"product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"X5kmV3z","title":"Lamm","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg","path":"product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.05,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"AFwEIkN","title":"Lammy","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png","path":"product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"JYcUni4","title":"Jess","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png","path":"product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.5,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":10,"type":"account","stock":14}],"groups":[{"id":"4TlYivf","title":"Minecraft Is","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["sYu98Kq","JucpDM8","qX4vLC2","7efhwnl","kBkgLAv"]},{"id":"GTXwlkU","title":"Streaming","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["JYcUni4","AFwEIkN","X5kmV3z"]}],"feedbacks":[{"updated_at":"2018-09-16 00:29:35","stars":5,"rating":1,"comment":"The best thing in the world! Thanks!","response":"Thank you so much! Come again!","product":null}],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"bear","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"p9YymiV","title":"fortnite","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":75,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"king","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"91vFhN4","title":"uplay","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":4,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"vX5IJ4T","title":"premium","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":2,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}}]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample json?

Comment: Sure, I will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your products JSON data which looks like below, the products data is deep inside `user` -> `products`. Also, the products itself is an array. So you will need 2 loops to achieve this. Outer one is to loop over users and inner one is to loop over each user's products and unset all those which have `stock` as `0`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [username] => Chris
                    [avatar] => https://s3-storage.//avatars/iiPjqYlVkijUv9XoPt0YUpyHuueBdkFkrTjIwnJd.gif
                    [rep] => Array
                        (
                            [positive] => 1
                            [neutral] => 0
                            [negative] => 0
                        )

                    [products] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => JucpDM8
                                    [title] => Non-Full Access(NFA)
                                    [image] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://s3-storage.//product_images/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png
                                            [path] => product_images/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png
                                        )

                                    [quantity] => Array
                                        (
                                            [min] => 25
                                            [max] => 1000000
                                        )

                                    [price] => 0.02
                                    [currency] => USD
                                    [stock_warning] => 500
                                    [type] => account
                                    [stock] => 12
```

)

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '[{"status":true,"user":{"username":"Chris","avatar":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/avatars\/iiPjqYlVkijUv9XoPt0YUpyHuueBdkFkrTjIwnJd.gif","rep":{"positive":1,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"JucpDM8","title":"Non-Full Access(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png","path":"product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png"},"quantity":{"min":25,"max":1000000},"price":0.02,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":500,"type":"account","stock":12},{"id":"qX4vLC2","title":"Unmigrated(UFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg","path":"product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":5.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"sYu98Kq","title":"Semi-Full(SFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg","path":"product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"7efhwnl","title":"Optifine Cape","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg","path":"product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":2,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"kBkgLAv","title":"Hypixel Ranked(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png","path":"product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"X5kmV3z","title":"Lamm","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg","path":"product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.05,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"AFwEIkN","title":"Lammy","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png","path":"product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"JYcUni4","title":"Hulu","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png","path":"product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.5,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":10,"type":"account","stock":14}],"groups":[{"id":"4TlYivf","title":"Minecraft Is","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["sYu98Kq","JucpDM8","qX4vLC2","7efhwnl","kBkgLAv"]},{"id":"GTXwlkU","title":"Streaming","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["JYcUni4","AFwEIkN","X5kmV3z"]}],"feedbacks":[{"updated_at":"2018-09-16 00:29:35","stars":5,"rating":1,"comment":"The best thing in the world! Thanks!","response":"Thank you so much! Come again!","product":null}],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"bear","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"p9YymiV","title":"fortnite","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":75,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"king","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"91vFhN4","title":"uplay with 40 game","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":4,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"vX5IJ4T","title":"spotify premium","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":2,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}}]';

$json_decoded = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($json_decoded as $index => $user_data){
    foreach($user_data['user']['products'] as $product_index => $product_data){
        if($product_data['stock'] == 0){
            unset($json_decoded[$index]['user']['products'][$product_index]);
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($json_decoded);
```

Comment: You are awesome, I don't know why I couldn't wrap my head around the array structure. I get perfect results and TIL something new. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: @JasonWaltz Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have another array in "products" key.
so you will have to add another foreach on $value["products"]
to check if stock is 0 for that product and modify code according to that.

It will be more good if you just unset that value in first code block so you will not need another for each.

```
$data = json_decode($data,true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['user']['products'] as $k => $v) {
        if($v['stock'] == 0){
            //unset it
        }
    }
}
```